# remove 2014 from wp_get_archives

Tags: archives, wp-get-archives

we have `wp_get_archives('type=monthly');` function that have a output like this:

```
Archives by Month:
January 2014
December 2013
November 2013
```

but I want style like a table that sorted by years:

```
2014
January
-------------
2013
December    November
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only filter i could find inside the wp_get_archives function is for displaying the links. Based on the get_archives_link filter, this should work, use it in your functions.php file:

```
$archive_year = 0;
add_filter('get_archives_link','wp_get_archive_grouped_by_year',10,2);
function wp_get_archive_grouped_by_year($link_html) {
    global $archive_year;
    //Get the year from the link(probably better if you change this to regexp)
    $year_new = explode(' ', $link_html);
    $year_new = explode('</a>',$year_new[2]);
    $year_new = $year_new[0];
    $year_html = '';

    //If the year is not display previously
    if ($year_new != $archive_year) {
        $archive_year = $year_new;
        $year_html = '<li class="year">'.$archive_year.'</li>';
    }

    //Remove the year from the month link
    $link_html = str_replace(' '.$archive_year, "", $link_html);

    //Return the new links and exclude a specific year:
    if($archive_year != '2014') {
        echo $year_html.$link_html;
    }
}
```

Results:

```
<li class="year">2014</li>
<li><a href='#'>January</a></li>
<li class="year">2013</li>
<li><a href='#'>November</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>April</a></li>
```

Comment: Check out the code again, it will exclude all of the posts from 2014